# Can't install NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

For the second day I've been trying to install a NuGet Package, specifically Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but the output I get is:

> NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (>= 5.1.1)' for 'net7.0-windows7.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source. Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'workers'.

I've tried changing versions, starting the project from scratch, changing NuGet sources, but nothing helped. I downloaded the package separately and added the source, but it still won't install.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Microsoft Documentation to try and resolve your error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1100

Comment: Are you using _.NET 7_? Are you using Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using .NET 7, however, it's unclear if you're using Visual Studio 2022. Nonetheless, one can create a new project and add the NuGet package without Visual Studio using [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) , [dotnet sln](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln), and [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package).

- [Download/install the .NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)
- Open a `cmd` window

**To see installed SDKs**:

- `dotnet --info`

**To see available templates**

- `dotnet new list`

**Create a new WinForms Application project** (name: WinFormsTest):

- `dotnet new winforms --framework <TargetFramework> --output <fully-qualified path>`

**For example, to create a new project in a subfolder of your *Documents* folder**:

**Note**: Below you'll notice two subdirectories with the same name (*WinFormsTest*). The first one is for the *solution* and the subfolder with the same name is for the *project* - this is the same structure Visual Studio creates.

```
 dotnet new winforms --framework net7.0 --output "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinFormsTest\WinformsTest"
```

see [TargetFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks)

**Create solution file**:

```
dotnet new sln --name "WinFormsTest" --output "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinFormsTest" --project "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinFormsTest\WinformsTest\WinFormsTest.csproj"
```

**Add Project to Solution File**:

```
dotnet sln "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinformsTest" add "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinformsTest\WinformsTest\WinformsTest.csproj"
```

[Search for desired NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/), for example NuGet package [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.data.sql)

**Download and add desired NuGet package to project** (ex: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)

```
dotnet add "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinFormsTest\WinformsTest\WinformsTest.csproj" package "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
```

**To Build/Run Application**:

```
dotnet run --project "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\WinFormsTest\WinformsTest\WinformsTest.csproj"
```

Use your favorite editor to develop/modify the Windows Forms Application (you may consider using [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)).