# Do I Have to Have Visual Studio 2022 Installed on Build Server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

To move code into production my employer uses a build server which creates the artifacts that will be deployed to testing and later production servers.  The latest version of Visual Studio loaded on this machine was 2017.  I wrote an application which needed .NET Core - so I had Visual Studio 2019 installed on the build server which also installed a number of older versions of the .NET SDK along with it.  The build failed because company policy states that no software which is out of support can be put on production servers - so all the versions of .NET Core SDK on the build server were removed!  I had the .NET Core 6 SDK installed to replace the earlier versions - but later realized it won't work with Visual Studio 2019.  Do I need to go back to the techies and have them also install Visual Studio 2022 on the build box?

Comment: just install the appropriate .net core sdk

Comment: You don't need a full-featured IDE at all, you can do just command-line. This in particular applies to build-servers. So `dotnet build` or whatever command is your friend.

Comment: Certainly no need to install VS to these servers. Build servers are not development environments and normally does not imlpy VS.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Answer (score 0):

Although [Visual Studio 2019 does not support .net 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5567#issuecomment-1105996161), you do not need to install Visual Studio 2022 on the server. Because normal development activities will not be performed on the server, you only need to install the corresponding .net sdk version.

And it seems that there are different versions of .net sdk in your operating environment, you can specify the corresponding .net sdk in the following way

Here is a simple example where I changed .net 7.0.100 to .net 6.0.408 using cmd:

[image]