# questions about C# .net installation and set up in visual studio code

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

> PS C:\Windows\System32> dotnet new console
> Template "Console App" could not be created.
> Failed to create template.
> Details: Error while processing file /content/ConsoleApplication-CSharp/Company.ConsoleApplication1.csproj
> Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\System32.csproj' is denied.

i can not identify the problem?
how can i solve this one

I want to set up visual studio code enviroment for C#. but it is showing an error

Comment: You are trying to create the project inside the `Windows\System32` folder (This folder needs `Administrator` rights). I guess that's not the location you want to create the solution anyway. Go to a different folder e.g. in your `Documents` and then rerun the command. I would suggest to use `dotnet new console -n "ProjectName"`.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Answer (score 0):

The path you are trying to access is reserved for system files that are required by the Windows Operating System to run on your computer. You cannot create a project here so you need to change the path where you are trying to create a project to another location that is a child folder of the Users folder. Visual Studio creates and saves new project files to this path by default **C:\Users\YourUserName\source\repos** but you can specify either a folder in the Documents or Downloads folder and the error won't be thrown.