# Create Desktop App from Command Promt - Windows Form .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How To create .NET Core Desktop app using Command Promt?

I have tried this and does not work

`dotnet new desktop -n Toha.CodeGenDesktopdotnet new desktop -n CodeGenDesktop`

I am also searching [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)  but does not find it on official microsoft

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly, I find the correct project type [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates)

So, the correct command is like this:

```
 dotnet new winforms -n CodeGenDesktop
```